# Project cannot read file

Tags: python, file, import

Hello I am using the Impractical python project book. I am having trouble getting a file to work in the first project. I am trying to use file twobit in load_dictionary.py then afterwards i am trying to import the whole file into palindromes.py. The code for load_dictionary.py is

```
import sys
def load(twobit):
# open a text file and return values lowercased
    try:
        with open(twobit) as in_file:
            loaded_txt= in_file.read().strip().split('\n')
            loaded_txt= [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
            return loaded_txt
    except IOError as e:
        print('{} \nError opening {}. Terminating program.'.format(e,file),file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I am not sure why it wont take the words within twobit and run it through load_dictionary.py
It says that there is no such file as twobit, and for the print('{} \nError... line it says that in_file was referenced berfore assignment

palindromes.py looks like this btw

```
import load_dictionary
word_list=load_dictionary.load('twobit')
pali_list=[]
for word in word_list:
    if len(word) > 1 and word == word[::-1]:
        pali_list.append(word)
print('\nNumber of palindromes found= {}\n'.format(len(pali_list)))
print(*pali_list, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Does twobit have an extension?

Comment: whether i attach an extension or not it does not seem to work. i tried changing it to txt in both the folder and the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and do what it suppose to do. Tested in Windows 10 with Python 3.6 and 3.8. Some recommendations to check:

- All these files must be in the same directory and with the right permissions.
- twobit file has to be a text file and must have at least read permissions for the actual user.
- Print `twobit` variable in load_dictionary.py to check its value.
- Try `in_file = open(twobit)` instead of `with open(twobit) as in_file:`. Don't forget to close the file.
- Try to check the content of twobit file and the line separators (CRLF for windows and LF for Linux).

Comment: Because the code is `open(twobit)` so the file must be a text file, not binary, because the defaults parameter for open() are `r` read and `t`text. [Open-doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: hello i tried the recommendations and i am getting closer i applied read only on the coding but when i try to print it out alone it gives a tb. it continues to say it is not defined. Another problem is that in_file=open(twobit) is a syntax error. Thank you for your help

Comment: What platform and Python versión área you using? Any additional info? Maybe you can also send the full error message and the way/command you're using to run your code

Comment: my except IOError is going through so I know it is that now after our adjustments I will go and read a chapter and get back to you on my findings. Trying to get my file to show that it exists

Comment: You can check the path of your file with `os.path.exists(path)` , if the file exist `os.path.exists(path)` or if is a file `os.path.isfile(path)`. Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: wait i got it i just had to use quotes around the open function. Definitely learned a lot during this thank you sir.